# Python listas cuando hago pop en una hace pop en la otra sin razon aparente?

Tags: python

Coloco un ejemplo de lo que me esta ocurriendo, igualo una lista vacia con una lista llena de elementos, y cuando hago pop en una hace pop en la otra pero necesito que cuando se vacie la segunda se vuelva a llenar con la primera

```
lista1 = ['elemento1','elemento1','elemento1','elemento1','elemento1','elemento1']
lista2 = []

for i in range(0,50):
  if not lista2: lista2=lista1
  lista2.pop(0)
  print('lista1:',lista1)
  print('lista2:',lista2)
```

el resultado de este codigo es:

```
Python 3.6.1 (default, Dec 2015, 13:05:11)
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux

lista1: ['elemento1', 'elemento1', 'elemento1', 'elemento1', 'elemento1']
lista2: ['elemento1', 'elemento1', 'elemento1', 'elemento1', 'elemento1']
lista1: ['elemento1', 'elemento1', 'elemento1', 'elemento1']
lista2: ['elemento1', 'elemento1', 'elemento1', 'elemento1']
lista1: ['elemento1', 'elemento1', 'elemento1']
lista2: ['elemento1', 'elemento1', 'elemento1']
lista1: ['elemento1', 'elemento1']
lista2: ['elemento1', 'elemento1']
lista1: ['elemento1']
lista2: ['elemento1']
lista1: []
lista2: []
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 6, in <module>
IndexError: pop from empty list
```

Comment: Las "variables" en Python son solo identificadores asociados a un objeto determinado, al hacer `lista2=lista1` lo único que haces es asignarle al identificador `lista2` el mismo objeto al que apunta `lista1`, ambos apuntan al mismo objeto `list`. Como se indica en las respuestas a la pregunta duplicada debes copiar la lista, `lista2 = copy.copy(lista1)` o `lista2 = lista1[::]` o `lista2 = lista1.copy()` si solo quieres copiar la lista pero no sus elementos (o estos son inmutables) o `lista2  = copy.deepcopy(lista1)` para realizar una copia recursiva. Si te quedan dudas comenta. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error es que estás haciendo un lista2=lista1, prueba así

```
for elem in lista1:
    lista2.append(elem)
```